Laravel seeder no rellena tabla con foreing keys
Estoy haciendo un proyecto en laravel y tengo las siguientes migraciones
public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id('customer_id');
            $table->string('first_name', 50);
            $table->string('last_name', 50);
            $table->string('address', 100)->nullable();
            $table->string('phone', 15)->nullable();
            $table->string('email', 50)->unique();
            $table->timestamp('registration_date')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('customers');
    }

public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('vehicles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id('vehicle_id');
            $table->foreignId('customer_id')->constrained('customers')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('make', 50);
            $table->string('model', 50);
            $table->year('year');
            $table->string('license_plate', 15)->unique();
            $table->string('vin', 17)->unique();
            $table->string('color', 20)->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('registration_date')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('vehicles');
    }

Como se puede ver en la tabla vehicles hay una clave foranea hacia la tabla customers os muestro la relacion en los modelos
class Vehicle extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * The primary key associated with the table.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $primaryKey = 'vehicle_id';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'customer_id',
        'make',
        'model',
        'year',
        'license_plate',
        'vin',
        'color',
        'registration_date',
    ];

    public function customer(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class, 'customer_id');
    }
}

class Customer extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * The primary key associated with the table.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $primaryKey = 'customer_id';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'address',
        'phone',
        'email',
        'registration_date',
    ];

    public function vehicles(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Vehicle::class, 'customer_id');
    }
}

Y por ultimo los factories
class CustomerFactory extends Factory
{

    protected $model = Customer::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function definition(): array
    {
        return [
            'first_name' => fake()->name(),
            'last_name' => fake()->lastName(),
            'address' => fake()->address(),
            'phone' => fake()->phoneNumber(),
            'email' => fake()->email(),
            'registration_date' => fake()->date(),
        ];
    }
}

class VehicleFactory extends Factory
{

    protected $model = Vehicle::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function definition(): array
    {
        return [
            'customer_id' => Customer::factory(),
            'make' => fake()->company,
            'model' => fake()->word,
            'year' => fake()->year,
            'license_plate' => strtoupper(fake()->unique()->bothify('???-####')),
            'vin' => strtoupper(fake()->unique()->bothify('?????????????????')),
            'color' => fake()->safeColorName,
            'registration_date' => fake()->date(),
        ];
    }
}

Al parecer el error que es el siguiente:
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 foreign key mismatch - "vehicles" referencing "customers" (Connection: sqlite, SQL: insert into "vehicles" ("customer_id", "make", "model", "yea
r", "license_plate", "vin", "color", "registration_date", "updated_at", "created_at") values (11, Wilderman Group, nostrum, 1970, VRF-4423, FVKRDKQWQHGDVFWBP, purple, 2019-01-16, 2024-11-13 18:30:33, 2024-11-13 18:30:33))

se debe a que esta intentando añadir como clave foranea en la tabla vehicles un cliente con el id 11 que claramente no existe porque solo se crean 10 clientes para 15 vehiculos. He probado a "forzar" que no aparezca el error haciendo un bucle con todos los vehiclos creados y asignandolos a los clientes existentes pero eso daba otro error y pense que seguramente tuviese algo mal aqui que seria mucho mas simple que hacerlo de una forma de la que no esta pensado para hacerlo asi. Si alguien sabe que puede estar mal? Muchas gracias
EDIT: No se si el problema pueda deberse al uso de sqlite?
PD: Estoy usando laravel 11

Probablement Customer::factory() esté instanciando un nuevo Customer, pero no persistiéndolo en la BD, como cuando le agregas el metodo ->create() al final. Si lo que quieres es usar un customer existente, puedes consultar el modelo y cargando uno al azar. Creo que hay una funcion inRandomOrder o algo así, y con first() cargas solo uno

O mejor, en la documentacion dan varias alternativas para manejar las relaciones https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent-factories#factory-relationships

Tienes que crear uno en la factoria hija que quede guardado en BD y luego en el campo correspondiente del hijo llamar a la variable que contiene la creacion padre, porque sino para laravel es uno nuevo y falla por integridad referencial

Gracias por los comentarios pero realmente el codigo es correcto el problema como ya comentaba era el proyecto que de alguna forma se rompio y no hacia las cosas como deberia. Al crear otro desde cero con el mismo codigo exacto funcionaba sin problemas

Finalmente despues de varios dias y muchisimas pruebas encontre que el fallo se debia al proyecto. Efecivamente tal y como se indica en la documentacion de los factorys de laravel la linea 'customer_id' => Customer::factory() en ningun caso deberia crear un customer si no escojer uno ya creado por eso a pesar de cambiar la logica a 'customer_id' => fake()->randomElement(Customer::all('id')) como bien me indico @williamrb segia con el mismo problema solo que esta vez en lugar de pasar en el registro 11 pasaba de forma aleatoria en el 6, 12, 4, etc... De alguna forma que ya me di por vencido el framework no funcionaba como deberia. Quizas sea por haber creado mas migraciones, seeders, factories y model erroneos en ese mismo proyecto y haberlas borrado mal el proyecto se haya roto y al fin al cabo ninguno sabemos al 100% sobre que hace exactamente laravel con las migraciones, factories, seeder etc... Total que de alguna forma termino funcionando cambiando la migracion de vehicles en la foreign key de:
$table->foreignId('customer_id')->constrained('customers')->onDelete('cascade');

a
$table->unsignedBigInteger('customer_id');
$table->foreign('customer_id')->references('customer_id')->on('customers')->onDelete('cascade');

Acabo funcionando. Pero dias despues vi que al usar las relaciones no funcionaban como deberia por lo que decidi crear un proyecto completamente nuevo desde 0 con exactamente el mismo codigo que puse en mi pregunta y funciono. Efectivamente el problema era el proyecto que ojala alguien sepa decirme porque haya podido ser para poder identificar estos problemas mas rapido

Puedes usar $table->foreignIdFor(Customer::class)->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete() y evitas declarar el campo y luego la llave foránea. Aquí puedes ver todos los tipos soportados por las migraciones en Laravel: Laravel Migrations

Si es lo que he comentado @williamrb con $table->foreignId('customer_id')->constrained('customers')->onDelete('cascade'); evitas declarar el campo y luego la clave foranea, y deberia cojer automaticamente la referencia por lo que el for no seria necesario, el problema es que en ese proyecto seguramente por lo que he comentado de que de crear y borrar archivos en ocasiones el ide borra una referencia a ese nombre de archivo que no deberia y el proyecto de laravel deja de funcionar bien

Deberías cambiar el Customer::factory() en tu VehicleFactory, aquí te muestro el factory corregido:
class VehicleFactory extends Factory
{

    protected $model = Vehicle::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function definition(): array
    {
        return [
            'customer_id' => fake()->randomElement(Customer::all('id')),
            'make' => fake()->company,
            'model' => fake()->word,
            'year' => fake()->year,
            'license_plate' => strtoupper(fake()->unique()->bothify('???-####')),
            'vin' => strtoupper(fake()->unique()->bothify('?????????????????')),
            'color' => fake()->safeColorName,
            'registration_date' => fake()->date(),
        ];
    }
}

de esta manera tomará un customer_id aleatorio de los customers ya registrados en la base de datos
